# Catching errors from ReactDOM.render using Try/Catch

Tags: reactjs, react-ssr

I'm trying to catch errors thrown from `ReactDOM.render` or `ReactDOMServer.renderToString`.

I can't use componentDidCatch, because I'm trying to simulate an error thrown in SSR.
I know that in SSR rendering there are no lifecycle hooks, so that's why I'm trying also with `ReactDOM.render`.

**Here is an example code**

A component throwing an error during render:

```
import React from 'react';

export class Test extends React.Component<any> {
  public componentDidMount(): void {
    this.setState(() => {
      throw new Error('Error');
    });
  }

  public render() {
    return <div>Hello</div>;
  }
}
```

And a code that tries to catch the thrown error:

```
try {
  const rendered = ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('root'));
  console.log(rendered);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

The result of this code is console log of the rendered component and not the thrown error.

By the way - the page is not rendered in the browser because of that error, but it still passes the "try" and not caught in the "catch". Why is that?

Is there a way to catch rendering errors programmatically like that?

Thanks.